# Meta classifier based on "or" logic in scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

How can I build a meta-classifier in `scikit-learn` out of `N` binary classifiers which will return `1` if any of the classifiers returns `1`?

Currently I've tried [`VotingClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html), but it lacks the logic that I need, both with `voting` equal to `hard` and `soft`. [`Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) seems to be oriented towards sequential computation

I can write the logic by myself, but I am wondering if there is anything built-in?

Comment: Downvoter, please explain what is wrong with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in options are only `soft` and `hard` voting. As you mentioned, we can create a custom function to this meta-classifier, which uses `OR` logic based on the source code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/ensemble/voting_classifier.py#L215).  This custom meta classifier can fit into the `pipeline` as well.

```py
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted
class CustomMetaClassifier(VotingClassifier):
    def predict(self, X):
        """ Predict class labels for X.
        Parameters
        ----------
        X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
            The input samples.
        Returns
        ----------
        maj : array-like, shape = [n_samples]
            Predicted class labels.
        """

        check_is_fitted(self, 'estimators_')

        maj = np.max(eclf1._predict(X), 1)

        maj = self.le_.inverse_transform(maj)

        return maj
```

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
>>> from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
>>> from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, VotingClassifier
>>> clf1 = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', multi_class='multinomial',
...                           random_state=1)
>>> clf2 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, random_state=1)
>>> clf3 = GaussianNB()
>>> X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
>>> y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
>>> eclf1 = CustomMetaClassifier(estimators=[
...         ('lr', clf1), ('rf', clf2), ('gnb', clf3)])
>>> eclf1 = eclf1.fit(X, y)
>>> eclf1.predict(X)
array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
```